# How to pass auth uid as a query parameter without getting undefined?

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, react-hooks, react-query

I am using react-query-firebase library to make a query to a document.

According to documentation this is how you make a query:

```
  const ref = doc(firestore, 'users', id);

  const product = useFirestoreDocument(["users", id], ref);
```

Everything ***works*** when I manually set id like this:

`const id = "pW5CizOJOpXezr5lGGsh";`

However I want to set the uid dynamically and I am using auth state hook as well:

```
const user = useAuthUser(["user"], auth);
const ref = doc(firestore, "users", user.data.uid);
```

the problem is that on page load user initializes as undefined and I need to wait for a split second for **user.data.uid** to populate and because of that I am getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined`

is there a way to skip making a query until user has finished loading and only then make a query.

Comment: Where are these hooks defined?

Comment: @samthecodingman imported them from: "@react-query-firebase/firestore" and "@react-query-firebase/auth"

Comment: Both of those hooks have a `isLoading` property. Using that value you can return `null` from your component to hide it until the state resolves. Based on that error, it looks like you are trying to use `product.data` before the data has been downloaded but without the rest of your code, we can't be sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with react-query, you would usually just `disable` the query until you have all the dependencies via the `enabled` property:

```
useQuery(["users", id], ref, { enabled: Boolean(id) }
```

This is documented in the [dependent queries section of the docs](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/dependent-queries).